# Buffered channel blocks execution

Tags: go

I have following code:

```
func (q *Queue) GetStreams(qi *QueueInfo) {
    channel := make(chan error, len(qi.AudioChunks))
    for _, audiInfo := range qi.AudioChunks {
        go audiInfo.GetStream(q.APIChunkURL, q.Sender, channel)
    }
    i := 0
    for err := range channel {
        fmt.Println(i)
        i++
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error getting audio", err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Passed")
}

func (au *AudioChunkPayload) GetStream(path string, rs *RequestSender, channel chan error) {
    completeURL := fmt.Sprintf(path, au.AudioChunkID)
    err := GetEncodedAudio(rs, completeURL)
    if err != nil {
        channel <- err
    } else {
        channel <- nil
    }
}
```

that where `GetStream` func is downloading some data. Most of the time, lenght of `qi.AudioChunks` is 8, but it is not a rule. My problem is, that program succesfully prints numer 0-7 (for 8 chunks) but it never proceed to next print (`fmt.Println(Passed)`). What I have had read about buffered channels, I thought that it should proceed, but obviously I am wrong. How can I make my func `GetStreams` proceed and finish?

Comment: Please show the source of `audiInfo.GetStream`.

Comment: Does the channel ever get closed? If not, please read [for statements with a range clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) from the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range loops over a channel until it's explicitly [`close`d](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close).

Buffering affects sending to a channel *not* receiving from the channel.

I'm trying to find the official docs but from [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4):

> The loop for i := range c receives values from the channel repeatedly
>   until it is closed.